# Navigation with jQuery scrollTop acting strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, scrolltop

I have a navigation on my website that is powered by jQuery to smooth-scroll to the target ID, but it is acting very strange:

- Sometimes it doesn't actually move to the target ID all the way
- If you click a second time on the target it scrolls you back up to the header

[**Here**](https://i.imgur.com/BW70gVO.gifv) is a gif demonstrating this weird behavior

---

I made a [**simplistic version**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/wauLkbxp/47/) of my navigation so you can test it yourself, although this one has none of the weird behavior. But I can't figure out what is causing this.

I made it as identical as possible. The HTML, classes, ID's and jQuery are **exactly** the same. I also gave the navigation a `fixed` position, just like the one on my website.

The jQuery code in question:

```
$("#scrollOne").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#one").offset().top
  }, 750);
});
```

In short, what could the problem be with my original code that would cause this strange behavior, compared to the JSFiddle that works as intended? If you need the original (full) code, please ask me directly because it is a freelance project that I can't just make public. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems the last one section changed the offset value to something strange. Try to console the scrollTop value.

Comment: You need to see the *original* code to help .. actually if we are not able to reproduce the issue we can do nothing

Comment: Yes possibly share the original one.

Comment: Thank you all, I should have done this right away so that's on me. I [posted my question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802245/navigation-with-jquery-smooth-scroll-causes-weird-behavior) with the original code that demonstrates the same behavior. I will delete this one in 24 hours so that you have enough time to find the new question.