# Navigation with jQuery smooth scroll causes weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, scrolltop

I have a navigation on my website that is powered by jQuery to smooth-scroll to the target ID, but it is acting very strange (Chrome, Firefox):

- Sometimes it doesn't actually move to the target ID all the way
- If you click a second time on the target it scrolls you back up to the header

[**Here**](https://i.imgur.com/BW70gVO.gifv) is a gif demonstrating this weird behavior on my website.

---

I made a [**simplistic version**](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/GYMvRv?editors=1010) of my website so you can test it yourself, where you can experience the same [**weird behavior**](https://i.imgur.com/vcL1a8u.gifv).

I made it as identical as possible. The HTML, classes, ID's and jQuery are **exactly** the same. I also gave the navigation a `fixed` position, just like the one on my website.

The jQuery code in question:

```
$("#scrollOne").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#one").offset().top
  }, 750);
});
```

In short, what could the problem be with code that would cause this strange behavior? Am I using the wrong method for jQuery and if so, is there a better one? I don't mind using a library, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Hello (and very well put question). I can't seem to reproduce the issue using your codepen, at least on Chrome (edit: same on FF). No matter how many times I click the header links, it scrolls down to the targets like it should... Any specific browser where it occurs?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox (I'll add that to the question). Try clicking on one of the nav items and then click it again, it will move all the way up to the header again. Or if you continue to move around with the navigation, it will start moving to random locations and sometimes all the way up to the header again for no reason. Because it's very random, it's really difficult to deduct what is causing this.

Comment: I must be missing something. On your codepen you have to scroll back up to see the nav links again right? I'm clicking a link, scrolling back up (with wheel or keyboard) and then click another link or the same one, and nothing weird is happening on my end.

Comment: OK, I'm dumb, I didn't read the text that said under 800px only. Let me try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version. Apparently this is due to the `overflow-x:hidden` from `body`'s CSS rule. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124874/how-to-scrolltop-when-html-body-is-set-to-height-100).

Removed that rule, now it seems perfectly fine (or prefer the codepen below that, since SO's fullpage version is bugging out a bit):

```js
$("#scrollOne").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#one").offset().top
  }, 750);
});

$("#scrollTwo").click(function(e) {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#two").offset().top
  }, 750);
});

$("#scrollThree").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#three").offset().top
  }, 750);
});

$("#scrollFour").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#four").offset().top
  }, 750);
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,600,700");
@keyframes nav-item {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100px) translateX(-20px); }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0) translateX(0); } }

@keyframes nav-item-alt {
  from {
    opacity: 0; }
  to {
    opacity: 1; } }

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%; }

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Muli, sans-serif;
  color: #656565;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url(../img/bg-pattern.png); }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 25em) {
    body {
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url(../img/bg-pattern-small.png); } }

.header-title {
  color: #262626;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-left: -3px; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 25em) {
    .header-title {
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 3px; } }

.header-sub {
  color: #262626;
  font-size: 2rem; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .header-sub {
      display: none; } }

.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: steelblue;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(min-content 1fr));
  grid-template-areas: "logo nav" 
 ". lang" 
 "cta cta"; }

.section-one {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
  padding: 3rem;
 background-color: gold;
}

.section-two {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
  padding: 3rem;
 background-color: tomato;
}

.section-three {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
  padding: 3rem;
 background-color: limegreen;
}

.section-four {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
  padding: 3rem;
 background-color: orange;
}

.navigation__checkbox {
  display: none; }

.navigation__button {
  display: none; }

@media only screen and (min-width: 50em) {
  .navigation__nav {
    display: inline-block;
    justify-self: end;
    grid-area: nav; }
  .navigation__list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none; }
  .navigation__link {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #262626;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    transition: transform .1s ease-in-out; } }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 50em) and (max-width: 68.75em) {
    .navigation__link {
      font-size: 2rem; } }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 50em) and (min-width: 50em) {
    .navigation__link::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: #262626;
      transition: transform .1s ease-in-out;
      transform: scaleX(0);
      transform-origin: right; }
    .navigation__link:hover {
      transform: translateY(-2px); }
    .navigation__link:hover::before {
      transform: scaleX(1);
      transform-origin: left;
      transition: transform .2s ease-in-out; } }

@media only screen and (min-width: 50em) {
  .navigation__item {
    margin-bottom: 1rem 0; }
    .navigation__item:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: 3rem; } }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 50em) and (max-width: 62.5em) {
      .navigation__item:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 2rem; } }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 50em) and (max-width: 56.25em) {
      .navigation__item:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 1rem; } }

@media only screen and (min-width: 50em) {
    .navigation__item:nth-child(1) {
      animation: nav-item .5s backwards ease-in-out 0s; }
    .navigation__item:nth-child(2) {
      animation: nav-item .5s backwards ease-in-out .2s; }
    .navigation__item:nth-child(3) {
      animation: nav-item .5s backwards ease-in-out .4s; }
    .navigation__item:nth-child(4) {
      animation: nav-item .5s backwards ease-in-out .6s; } }

@media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
  .navigation__nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0; }
  .navigation__list {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center; }
  .navigation__item {
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
    opacity: 0; }
  .navigation__link:link, .navigation__link:visited {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, #fff 50%);
    background-size: 250%;
    transition: all ease-in-out .5s, transform ease-in-out .25s; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) and (max-width: 37.5em) {
    .navigation__link:link, .navigation__link:visited {
      font-size: 2.5rem; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) and (max-width: 25em) {
    .navigation__link:link, .navigation__link:visited {
      font-size: 2rem; } }

@media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
  .navigation__link:hover, .navigation__link:active {
    color: #FFE20C;
    background-position: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-1rem); } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 50em) and (max-width: 25em) {
    .navigation__link:hover, .navigation__link:active {
      transform: none; } }

@media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
  .navigation__button {
    grid-area: nav;
    justify-self: end;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 1.5rem;
    right: calc(1.5rem);
    width: 6rem;
    height: 6rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 3rem rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 300; }
    .navigation__button:active {
      transform: scale(0.9); }
  .navigation__background {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 3rem;
    right: calc(3rem);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#FFE20C, #FF200C);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: transform 0s .75s,
 opacity .5s linear .25s; } }

.navigation__checkbox:checked ~ .navigation__background {
  transform: scale(100);
  opacity: .8;
  transition: transform 1.5s,
 opacity .5s; }

.navigation__checkbox:checked ~ .navigation__nav {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s .5s;
  z-index: 200; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 50em) {
  .navigation__checkbox:checked ~ .navigation__nav .navigation__list {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1; }
  .navigation__checkbox:checked ~ .navigation__nav .navigation__item:nth-child(1) {
    animation: nav-item-alt .25s forwards ease-in-out 0s; }
  .navigation__checkbox:checked ~ .navigation__nav .navigation__item:nth-child(2) {
    animation: nav-item-alt .25s forwards ease-in-out .2s; }
  .navigation__checkbox:checked ~ .navigation__nav .navigation__item:nth-child(3) {
    animation: nav-item-alt .25s forwards ease-in-out .4s; }
  .navigation__checkbox:checked ~ .navigation__nav .navigation__item:nth-child(4) {
    animation: nav-item-alt .25s forwards ease-in-out .6s; }
  .navigation__checkbox:checked ~ .navigation__language {
    display: flex; } }

.navigation__icon {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3rem; }
  .navigation__icon, .navigation__icon::before, .navigation__icon::after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #656565;
    transition: all .25s; }
  .navigation__icon::before, .navigation__icon::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; }
  .navigation__icon::before {
    transform: translateY(-1rem); }
  .navigation__icon::after {
    transform: translateY(1rem); }

.navigation__button:hover .navigation__icon {
  transform: scale(0.8); }

.navigation__checkbox:checked + .navigation__button .navigation__icon {
  background: transparent; }

.navigation__checkbox:checked + .navigation__button .navigation__icon::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-135deg); }

.navigation__checkbox:checked + .navigation__button .navigation__icon::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg); }

.navigation__checkbox:checked + .navigation__button:hover .navigation__icon {
  transform: scale(0.8); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Header -->
<header class="header" id="header">
 <input class="navigation__checkbox" id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox">

 <label class="navigation__button" for="nav-toggle">
  <span class="navigation__icon"></span>
 </label>

 <div class="navigation__background"></div>

 <div class="company">
  <h2 class="header-title">Company</h2>
  <h3 class="header-sub">Hambuger menu shown under 800px width</h3>
 </div>

 <nav class="navigation__nav">
  <ul class="navigation__list">
   <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link scroll" id="scrollOne" href="#one">One</a></li>
   <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link scroll" id="scrollTwo" href="#two">Two</a></li>
   <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link scroll" id="scrollThree" href="#three">Three</a></li>
   <li class="navigation__item"><a class="navigation__link scroll" id="scrollFour" href="#four">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>

<!-- About -->
<section class="section-one" id="one">
 <h2 class="header-title">One</h2>
</section>

<!-- Quote -->
<section class="section-two" id="two">
 <h2 class="header-title">Two</h2>
</section>

<!-- Reviews -->
<section class="section-three" id="three">
 <h2 class="header-title">Three</h2>
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<section class="section-four" id="four">
 <h2 class="header-title">Four</h2>
</section>
```

[Codepen version](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdwwrR?editors=1111)

Unrelated: I would also suggest adding `.stop()` before each `.animate()` call so every new animation stops the previous one.

Comment: You were right, all that was required was to remove `body ( overflow-x: hidden; )`! Since your solution didn't require adding anything but rather removing unnecessary code that fixed it, it's better. But all other answers worked just fine, too :)

Answer (score 0):

`offset().top` values change when page scrolled. so, you need to save those values at the beginning, also you should re-assign those values when window size changes.

```
    var oneTop = $("#one").offset().top;
    var twoTop = $("#two").offset().top;
    var threeTop = $("#three").offset().top;
    var fourTop = $("#four").offset().top;
```

code: https://codepen.io/peker-ercan/pen/wYrrWV?editors=1010

Comment: This works perfectly, and your explanation also really helps me understand why it didn't work in the first place, and how your solution does work. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SirExotic Actually, just removing `overflow-x:hidden` (my answer) was simplest, and I believe most appropriate too (don't have to change the actual height of anything, and elements' positions will remain correct at any point, which they should). Whatever works best for you though, I suppose :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `height:100%` on the `body`, so the offset returns wrong values (*correct, but not what you expect*).

Give `height:auto` and `min-height:100%` to `body` and it will work correctly.

See updated pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJPPeL?editors=1010